# I am getting this error Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, exception, token

E/FirebaseInstanceId(13349): Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS. Won't retry the operation.
E/flutter (13349): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS

how can i solve this error ?

E/FirebaseInstanceId(13349): Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS. Won't retry the operation.
E/flutter (13349): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] java.io.IOException: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS